# spawn: command not found

Tags: linux, shell

```
root@ol8vm2 soft]# cat test2.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh tahmid@192.168.68.65
expect "password: "
send "Root@123\r"
expect "$ "
pwd
ls
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
[root@ol8vm2 soft]#


[root@ol8vm2 soft]# sh test2.sh
test2.sh: line 3: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "password: ": no such file or directory
test2.sh: line 5: send: command not found
couldn't read file "$ ": no such file or directory
/soft
script.exp  test2.sh
couldn't read file "$ ": no such file or directory
test2.sh: line 10: send: command not found
[root@ol8vm2 soft]#
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong shell.

You are running the command `sh test2.sh`. When you do this the shell that is defined in the first line ( `#!/bin/...`)  is ignored and the calling shell is used instead.

Run your script directly or invoke it with expect instead of sh.

Comment: thanks thats solve my issue.